# How Rollerworks/strength-validator setup

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

Hi I'm really new with symfony and the idea of this is kinda new to me specially how the framework behaves. I'm using Symfony 2.8 (due to project demand). Now I need to implement a password strength validator using [RollerWorks/strength-password-validator](https://github.com/rollerworks/PasswordStrengthValidator) now the instruction here is not clear and I don't know where to start. I even don't know what the anotation mean. There are some sample that make use of this validation but is using an yml file just like [THIS](http://www.pimwiddershoven.nl/entry/password-complexity-and-blacklist-in-symfony-optionally-with-fosuserbundle?fbclid=IwAR0w2HeA1Rsm5uQox0Em3-OWCn0VDBbhnBFDZEis3pFPVP9F8BfeLSNwTG8)

It's just not clear on how do I start with this. I added

```
new Rollerworks\Bundle\PasswordStrengthBundle\RollerworksPasswordStrengthBundle(),
```

in the AppKernel under the `registerBundles` function. Then on the UserBundle/Entity under User.php file I added this

```
use Rollerworks\Component\PasswordStrength\Validator\Constraints as RollerworksPassword;

/**
 * @RollerworksPassword\PasswordStrength(minLength=7, minStrength=3)
 */
protected $password;
```

But upon registration nothing happens. It still accept even if I use less than 7 password strength even the simplest password does not work. Any idea on this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Does validation work for other's filed ? maybe you need to install validator componenet

Comment: Yes validation for other component is working (although I'm not the one who created it). I think the validation is the default of the userbundle

Comment: Maybe you should add constraints validation under `plainPassword` not `password` propriety.  Could verify with with simple Assert\Length https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#basic-usage and tell me if it works or not

Comment: I tried this one. I added the Rollerworks to the $plainpassword but still no luck. Do I need to do some cache clear or something to make this work?

Comment: I dont think so, but you can try `bin/console cache:clear`  just try with a simple Assert validation like Itold you

Comment: Tried and still no luck